# Computers: what is the difference between load and loading?

Tags: word-difference, terminology

Please, tell me if a noun load and a noun loading are interchangeable? Can I say "fast document load" or "slow image loading"? Are these two words synonyms?

Comment: consider the difference between *talk* and *talking*

Comment: @Mr. twister or *run* and *running*. I don't know how to explain this precisely, but you may think of *load, talk, run* as an act, an instance of such activity, usually a complete act, and think of *loading, talking, running* as the activity itself, a concept of such activity, an abstract idea of such activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun version of loading can be the abstract as commented above, but because it tends to refer to a process rather than an event, it is also natural and common to use it in referring to things that take some time.  "Document loading" implies it is(was/will be) ongoing.  That is not due to your slow/fast although the effects of those adjectives in your examples reinforce the effect of the verbs.

Load can be a noun or active verb.  Noun: "Waiting for the document load to finish"  Verb: "Waiting for the document to load"

Loading can be noun or passive verb.  Noun: "Document loading in progress"  Verb "The document is loading"

I know you only asked about the noun usage, but the verb usages have the same difference.  Event vs process.

Comment: Thank you, @elc! I think I understand, but I'm not sure my understanding is clear. I see that you are a developer, so can I ask you how I can name a process of lazy loading of images? Many people use a definition `lazy load`, while according to what you have said, in my opinion, this process is refered to `lazy loading`, because it is a process, not a single action. So, where is the truth?

Comment: I think for naming something it would be natural to use lazy_load which can be interpreted either as the event "start a lazy load" or as the imperative "load something! (lazily)".  Or maybe for something like a handler or daemon it might be lazy_loader.   "Lazy_loading" is more like something you might see in a log event written by that code "lazy loading, ran out of memory".

Comment: What about of the concept of `lazy loading`, does it exist If a mean a concept, not an event or the imperative?

Comment: Yes, that certainly is the way to refer to the concept.  So a module or api might be a 'lazy loading' library.  Or a comment on a section of code might be "lazy loading happens here".  But again, methods or functions tend to be phrased more actively--in terms of events or actors rather than in terms of operational modes.